# Automatically call API from Postman and generate a JSON response in a file

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am using Postman to call API. I have a couple to call, so I made a collection and I am able to run it.
I am trying to get the results of the API saved in a file (JSON is fine) and then everytime I call the API, to get the file updated. It is possible to automatically save a response for each API call?
Could you please how can I do it? I have tried with newman, but I`m not being succesful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get results in JSON files, although I have to update it manually. Followed this video on [Youtube](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj26LCYson4AhVChFwKHYCABrgQwqsBegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DcCRmry10874&usg=AOvVaw1C2p7k-4zDjKZLMN9mrVq4) and this is the code in .js (if helps anyone in the future)

```
const newman = require('newman'); // require newman in your project
const fs = require('fs');

// call newman.run to pass `options` object and wait for callback
newman.run({
    collection: require('./name_of_postman_collection.json'),
    reporters: 'cli'
}).on('beforeRequest', (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
    console.log(data);
})
.on('request', (error, data) =>{
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }

    const fileName = `response ${data.item.name}.json`;
    const content = data.response.stream.toString();

    fs.writeFile(fileName, content, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

I am still trying to find out how to automate the process, to get refreshed files every 2-3 hours for example.